# why $('#main-content').children('p').html() doesn't work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry i am a beginner in jQuery and new in stackoverflow, it is hard for me to tell the differences from those DOM elements.
I want to change the innerHTML in the `<p>` element, but something strange happened..

For example

html code:

```
<div id='main-content'> 
    <p id='p0'>0</p>
    <p>0</p>
</div>
```

js code:

```
var p=$('#main-content').children('p');

$('#p0').html('100');
p[1].html('100');
```

I want to change the innerHTML of the first and second

element from 0 into 100, but the second method p[1].html('100') doesn't work...and the console said that TypeError: p[1].html is not a function. please help me, Firebug told me that $('#p0') is [object object] and p[1] is [object HTMLParagraphElement], could u explain the differences to me, thank u so much TAT

Comment: If you want both values to be the same then just use: `$('#main-content').children('p').html('100');` - http://jsfiddle.net/6bjvf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery also supports [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selectors. So you have that option as well. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrqwC/)**

```
$("#main-content p:nth-child(2)").text("100");
```

Like dystroy said, accessing jQuery arrays will return DOM elements. You can use a helper like eq, or simply create another jQuery object by wrapping the DOM element again. So, for example to fix your original code, just do:

```
var p=$('#main-content').children('p');
$(p[1]).html('100');
```

**Edit**: I reread the question, and it seems you want to update content of **both** paragraph elements. In this case, it becomes even simpler:

```
$("#main-content p").text("100");
```

jQuery will act on all selected objects. Please read up on how jQuery uses [css selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 4):

That's because `p[1]`, just like `p.get(1)`, returns the DOM element.

Use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the jQuery object at index `1` in the set :

```
p.eq(1).html('100');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//For First Paragraph with id 'p0';
$('#main-content').find("#p0").html("100");

//For second Paragraph;
$($('#main-content p')[1]).html("100");
```

Comment: Why would you first select the parent and then use `.find()` if you know the id of the element you're looking for?